# How to Suppress Horizontal Scrollbar on Table

Tags: google-visualization

I would like a Google Visualization Table with a fixed width and **td** cells that wrap.  When I specify a width in the draw method a horizontal scroll bar appears.  Rather than this, I want wrapping of cells.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mschenkel/obmk9rad/3/) is a working example.  In this example I would like for the first column to wrap.  I have tried adding a class with **word-wrap: break-word;**.  But this does not work.

Here is relevant js:

```
function drawChart() {
var cssClassNames = {
    'tableCell': 'googlecell'
};

var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

datatable.addColumn('string', 'Keyword', 'col1');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'Pageviews');
datatable.addColumn('number', 'Secs.');


datatable.addRows(3);
datatable.setCell(0, 0, '(not set)');
datatable.setCell(0, 1, 20308);
datatable.setCell(0, 2, 68.74);
datatable.setCell(1, 0, '(not provided)');
datatable.setCell(1, 1, 14410);
datatable.setCell(1, 2, 49.99);
datatable.setCell(2, 0, 'product_type_l1==sdsssijven&+product_type_l2==*');
datatable.setCell(2, 1, 3838);
datatable.setCell(2, 2, 48.35);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

table.draw(datatable, {
    showRowNumber: false,
        'allowHtml': true,
        'cssClassNames': cssClassNames,
    width: 400
});



}

google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart", "table"]
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

And relevant css:

```
.googlecell {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
.googlecell {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Is that what you are after? ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8y826Ld/))

[image]